# Key values of CSV incorrect causing key error

Tags: python, csv, keyerror

I have csv file from which I am trying to extract a particular column but I get keyerror. When I try to print the keys of the csv, I get this result:

```
[None, 'Id;"PostTypeId";"ParentId";"AcceptedAnswerId";"OwnerUserId";"LastEditorUserId";"OwnerDisplayName";"LastEditorDisplayName";"UserIdCombined"']
```

Code I tried:

```
    read_file = open ("ml_sample_complete.csv","r") # open input file for reading
    col_dict = {}
    with open('out.csv', 'wb') as f: # output csv file
        writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('ml_sample_complete.csv','r') as csvfile: # input csv file
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            print(row.keys())
            print(row["Tags"])
            col_dict.update(row)
    print(col_dict)
    read_file.close()
```

Please help me understand what is wrong here and how to rectify it.

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that your delimter should be ',' and not a ';' in the dictreader function.

Comment: Thank you! I missed noticing such a trivial thing.